# Is there an application that allows to search across Evernote, Todoist, Google Keep, Twitter

Tags: note-taking, search, search-engine, evernote

I extensively use web applications for organizing my thoughts and notes, some of those go to Evernote, some go to Todois, some are left in Google Drive, something is on Twitter.

I wonder if there an application that provides one search bar to search all my records across all those services I've posted to?

Comment: That sounds like a bad practice and poor organization as you can already see by your issue. Scattering information across different platforms will only lead to issues and make it hard to access, search, index and organize

Comment: I would advise you to keep all of your thoughts at one place. I recommend OneNote and Google Keep

Answer (score 1):

Searching directly to so different build applications and getting back results is quite difficult and I don't believe such a product exists.

What you might be able to do is through IFTTT create recipes so whenever you take a note or create a new todo in todoist create a new row in a Google Sheet, same for twitter and then search in that spreadsheet?